How to Solve a Piecewise PDE System in Mathematica?
I'm working on a problem involving the transverse vibration of a piecewise beam system. The system consists of two segments with different properties (length, Young's modulus, second moment of area, density, and cross-sectional area). The beam is fixed at both ends, and in the middle there are time-dependent moment loads. For simplicity, here we assume that all the parameters equal to 1. The following is a brief description of the model:

Here is my code, however, it cannot work.
L1 = 1; (*Length of first segment*)
L2 = 1; (*Length of second segment*)
EI1 = 1; EI2 = 1; \[Rho]S1 = 1; \[Rho]S2 = 1;
(*Governing Equations*)
eq1 = EI1*D[w1[x, t], {x, 4}] + \[Rho]S1*D[w1[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0;
eq2 = EI2*D[w2[x, t], {x, 4}] + \[Rho]S2*D[w2[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0;
(*Boundary Conditions*)
bc1 = {w1[0, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][w1][0, t] == 0}; (*Fixed at left end*)
bc2 = {Derivative[2, 0][w2][L1 + L2, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[3, 0][w2][L1 + L2, t] == 0}; 
(*Continuity Conditions*)
cc = {w1[L1, t] == w2[L1, t], 
  Derivative[1, 0][w1][L1, t] == Derivative[1, 0][w2][L1, t], 
  Derivative[3, 0][w1][L1, t] == Derivative[3, 0][w2][L1, t], 
  Derivative[2, 0][w1][L1, t] - Derivative[2, 0][w2][L1, t] == 
   Sin[t]}
(*Initial Conditions*)
ic = {w1[x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][w1][x, 0] == 0, w2[x, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][w2][x, 0] == 0};
(*Solve the PDEs*)
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, bc1, bc2, cc, ic}, {w1, w2}, {x, 0, 
   L1 + L2}, {t, 0, 10}]

I've written the following Mathematica code to solve the problem, but I'm not sure if I've implemented it correctly. Could someone please help me verify the approach or provide suggestions

NDSolve gives error message "NDSolve::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two.". I think you have to transform your equations in a form which contains w, moment

Perhaps you might avoid piecewise pde system if you  set moment  M as a line load q[x]=M DiracDelta'[x-L1] 

@UlrichNeumann Thanks for the advice! I'll give it a try. Additionally, I'm curious if there are any direct solving methods available.

@UlrichNeumann I'm having trouble getting the DiracDelta function to work. Based on my understanding, the system is now mechanically correct. Could you provide some advice or insight?  L1 = 1; L = 2;  EI = 1; \[Rho]S = 1; eq = EI*D[w[x, t], {x, 4}] + \[Rho]S*D[w[x, t], {t, 2}] ==     Sin[t]*DiracDelta'[x - L1]; bc1 = {w[0, t] == 0,     Derivative[1, 0][w][0, t] == 0}; (*Fixed at left end*) bc2 = {Derivative[2, 0][w][L, t] == 0, Derivative[3, 0][w][L, t] == 0}; ic = {w[x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][w][x, 0] == 0}; sol = NDSolve[{eq, bc1, bc2, ic}, w[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, 10}]

Yes something like that. But don't forget to transform your pdes to second order. Unfortunately NDSolve can't handle DiracDelta, that's why you should provide an approximation  dirac = Function[x,  1/Sqrt[2 Pi \[CurlyEpsilon]] Exp[-(x^2/(2 \[CurlyEpsilon]))]] /. \[CurlyEpsilon] -> .001

NDSolve is able to solve this 4th order problem if  we choose MethodOfLines and TensorProductGrid:
The discrete moment M=Sin[t] appears as loadforce DiracDelta'[x-L1]Sin[t] in the beam equation and must be approximated by dirac'[x-L1]Sin[t]for numerical reasons
L1 = L2 = 1;
dirac = Function[x,1/Sqrt[2 Pi \[CurlyEpsilon]]Exp[-(x^2/(2 \[CurlyEpsilon]))]] /. \[CurlyEpsilon] -> 1/1000;
Plot[dirac'[x - L1], {x, 0, L1 + L2}, PlotRange -> All,PlotLabel -> "Force pair"]


W = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[4, 0][w][x, t] + 
     Derivative[0, 2][w][x, t] == dirac'[x - L1] Sin[t],
   w[0, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][w][0, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[2, 0][w][L1 + L2, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[3, 0][w][L1 + L2, t] == 0, w[x, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][w][x, 0] == 0}, w, {x, 0, L1 + L2} , {t, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid"   , 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}, 
  MaxStepSize -> 1/500 (* ?timestep? *)
  ]

Plot3D[W[x, t], {x, 0, L1 + L2}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All,MeshFunctions -> (#2 &)]


Hope it helps too!

Thanks for the advice! Your methods have solved my problem and opened up my mind. I'm truly grateful for your guidance!

You're welcome!

Here a solution using Differences method. For the sake of simplicity I assumme EI=1,rho=1
We don't need a piecewise model if we apply the moment as a force pair
L1=L2=1;
dx = (L1 + L2)/20
xgrid = Range[0, L1 + L2 , dx] ;

nx = Length[xgrid];
M4 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[4], xgrid, 
    DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
M3 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[3], xgrid, 
    DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, 
    DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
    DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
u = Table[uu[i][t], {i, nx}];
gln = M4 . u + D[u, {t, 2}];

(* Moment M near x==L1: force pair *)
pos1 = Position[xgrid, L1 ][[1, 1]]; 
gln[[pos1 - 1]] = gln[[pos1 - 1]] - Sin[t]/(2 dx);
gln[[pos1 + 1]] = gln[[pos1 + 1]] + Sin[t]/(2 dx);

(* bc x==0 *)
gln[[1 ;; 2]] = D[{u[[1 ]], First[M1 . u]}, {t, 2}];

(* bc x=L1+L2 *)
gln[[-2 ;; -1]] = 
  Map[#[[1]] - #[[2]] &, 
   D[Solve[{Last[M2 . u], Last[M3 . u]} == 0, 
      u [[-2 ;; -1]]][[1]] , {t, 2}]  ];

gln is the set of ode's to be solved
ic = Map[{(# /. t -> 0) == 0, (D[#, t] /. t -> 0) == 0} &, u] //Flatten;
sol = NDSolve[{Map[# == 0 &, gln], ic}, u, {t, 0, 10}][[1]];
Plot[Evaluate[u /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]


Result looks like a standing wave.
deflection of the beam
Module[{usol = Function[t, Evaluate[u /. sol]]}, 
Manipulate[ListPlot[Evaluate[Transpose[{xgrid, usol[t]}]] , 
PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {{t, 0}, 0, 10}]]


Hope it helps!
